# How to pass argument via a .bat file to another program for Java?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I have a question regarding the evaluation of my code using a evaluator program by accessing it via a batch file. I have pasted the batch file code below.

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and TASK_SMALLEST_POLYGON_EVALUATOR_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
echo %JAVA_EXE%
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
echo %JAVA_HOME%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=D:\Programs\Java\programming\Polygon\bin\testerexec.jar
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=D:\Programs\Java\programming\Polygon\bin\testerexec.jar

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\task-smallest-polygon-evaluator.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\scala-logging_2.13-3.9.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.10.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\scallop_2.13-3.3.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\scala-reflect-2.13.0.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\scala-library-2.13.1.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\jackson-core-2.10.2.jar;%APP_HOME%\lib\paranamer-2.8.jar
echo %JAVA_OPTS%
echo %TASK_SMALLEST_POLYGON_EVALUATOR_OPTS%
echo done
@rem Execute task-smallest-polygon-evaluator
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %TASK_SMALLEST_POLYGON_EVALUATOR_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.simscale.smallestpolygon.Evaluator %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
pause
:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable TASK_SMALLEST_POLYGON_EVALUATOR_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%TASK_SMALLEST_POLYGON_EVALUATOR_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

There is an evaluator which needs to evaluate my code. I would like to know how to pass an argument to this batch file. I tried to input in the argument a location of my .jar file but I get an error of

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\Programs\Java\programming\Polygon\bin\testerexec.jar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>
> ERROR com.simscale.util.Util$ - unexpected exception in thread
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -jar "D:\New folder\task-smallest-polygon-evaluator\bin\testerexec3.jar"": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I have tried 2 kinds of arguments in the input, but none of them seem to work

> An evaluator program is supplied. This program receives one positional argument, which is the
> executable file (entry point for the target program – your program).

The positional argument I am passing is generating an error. Could somebody help me on how to pass this positional argument?
What inputs must be given in the bat file?

Comment: your code is too long and you didn't really specify what caused the problem. but i guess that your first parameter `D:\Programs\Java\programming\Polygon\bin\testerexec.jar` is not a valid Win32 executable.
Edit: Oops! I didn't see that you wrote that in the question.

Comment: Could you suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it as a window service first and run the service.

download the nssm using this link: https://nssm.cc/release/nssm-2.24.zip 
Then, install your .jar file as a windows service first. 
Sample code to install as a service:
nssm install serviceName url-to-java-exec url-to-Jar-file

Hope this is helpful